# Get content after question mark in PHP

Tags: php, query-string

I am getting a request like this and the url looks like this : www.site.com/test.php?id=4566500

Now am trying to get the id number to make the code in test page work, is there a way to do this?

```
<?php

echo("$id"+500);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can access these values via the `$_GET` array:

```
<?php

echo($_GET['id'] + 500);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basic PHP. You want to use the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
echo $_GET['id'] + 500;
```

Comment: iam newbie to php , can you tell me how , in the supervise example , how to make my test.page code get the id when anybodey hit a link similar to it ?

Comment: I thought i just did?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to check the right setting of your Getter parameter:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && preg_match("\d+", $_GET['id'])) {
    // do something with $_GET['id']
} else {
    // appropriate error handling
}
```

Remember that anyone can set the `id` parameter to any value (which can lead to possible [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

Comment: so is there a way to prevent this possible XSS attacks ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Check each value, which can be theoretically altered by other users (like getter or post parameters, values from text fields, ...) You have to check whether the values have a format/are in a range you expect them to be.

Comment: One example: The above code Checks whether the ``id`` parameter is set and whether it consists of one to many digit characters...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access direct url parameter without using predefined PHP super global variable like `$_GET["$parameter"] OR $_REQUEST["$parameter"]`.

So for : www.site.com/test.php?id=4566500

```
<?php
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];     // Or  $_REQUST['id'];
    if(is_numeric($id)){
        echo $id + 500;
    }else{
        echo $id;
    }

?>
```

For more detail : 
[PHP $_GET Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

[PHP $_REQUEST Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)